# Вопрос по Vue.Как сделать автоматическое удаление класса с интервалом в 2 секунды?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Помогите,пожалуйста,дописать код. Суть заключается в том,что необходимо удалить класс opacity_deactivated у каждого элемента с интервалом в 2 секунды.Подскажите как можно реализовать данную идею.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#header',
  data:{
    menuItems:[
        {
          url:'#',
          name:'Блог',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          url:'#',
          name:'Обо мне',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          url:'#',
          name:'Навыки',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          url:'#',
          name:'Блог',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          url:'#',
          name:'Услуги',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          url:'#',
          name:'Портфолио',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          url:'#',
          name:'Контакты',
          isActive: true
        }
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    activated: function(){
      this.menuItems.forEach
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<ul class="header_navmenu" id="header">
            <li class="nav_menu-item" 
            v-for="menu_item in menuItems"
            :class="{ opacity_deactivated: menu_item.isActive }">
            <a v-bind:href="menu_item.url" target="_blank">{{ menu_item.name }}</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 mounted(){
    this.menuItems.forEach((it,index)=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.$set(this.menuItems, index, {it,isActive: false})
      },2000 * (index+1))
    })
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение)

Comment: Всегда рад помочь.